# How to have meaningful awaitility failure?

Tags: java, awaitility

I would like be able to receive meaningful errors, for example

```
Set set = new HashSet();
await().until(() -> set.contains("foo"));
// during waiting
set.add("bar")
// after timeout
"Condition 'foo' should be in set=['bar'] not fulfilled
```

I can write

```
await().alias("'foo' should be in set").until(() -> set.contains("foo"));
```

and get

```
"Condition with alias 'foo' should be in set not fulfilled
```

But I would like to see set **content** when condition was timeouted

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @StephenCleary Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible by setting a `conditionEvaluationListener` ([awaitility/awaitility#102](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/issues/102)):

```
await()
    .conditionEvaluationListener(new ConditionEvaluationListener() {
      @Override public void conditionEvaluated(final EvaluatedCondition condition) {}
      @Override public void onTimeout(final TimeoutEvent event) {
        System.error.println("Timeout waiting for 'foo'. Set contains: " + set);
      }
    })
    .util(() -> set.contains("foo"));
```

You might also find this old Google Groups thread helpful: [Custom messages or method calls on success and timeout](https://groups.google.com/g/awaitility/c/TaOD78b93jE)